# kobject_init issue in 2.6.30 kernel

Tags: linux, kernel, device-driver

it seems that kobject_init was changed (I am a newbye) and actually my sample device driver I found on internet is not working.

I need absolutely a sample regarding /procs/sysfs and for these reasons I did not use a simpler sample.

This is the code I use :

```
int int_init(void)
{
int i, ret;

kint = kmalloc(sizeof(*kint), GFP_KERNEL);
if (!kint) return -ENOMEM;
memset(kint, 0, sizeof(*kint));
kobject_init(&kint->kobj);
kint->numbers[0] = 0;
kint->numbers[1] = 1;
kint->numbers[2] = 5;
kint->kobj.ktype = &ktype_int;

ret = kobject_set_name(&kint->kobj, "sample-int-range");
if (!ret) ret = kobject_add(&kint->kobj);
if (!ret) {
     for (i=0; i<3; i++)
         sysfs_create_file(&kint->kobj,kint_default_attrs[i]);
}

if (ret)
    kfree(kint);
 return ret;
}

void int_exit(void)
{

 int i;

 for (i=0; i<3; i++)
     sysfs_remove_file(&kint->kobj,
               kint_default_attrs[i]);
 kobject_del(&kint->kobj);
 kobject_put(&kint->kobj);
 /* wait untile the kobj is freed */

 while (kint) {
     schedule_timeout(HZ/2);
 }
 return;
}
module_init(int_init);
module_exit(int_exit);
```

And this is the error I catch (line no match):

> make: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-source-2.6.32'
>     CC [M]  /home/pietro/driver/sysfs.o
>   /home/pietro/driver/sysfs.c: In function ‘int_init’:
>   /home/pietro/driver/sysfs.c:125: error: too few arguments to function ‘kobject_init’
>   /home/pietro/driver/sysfs.c:132: error: too few arguments to function ‘kobject_add’
>   /home/pietro/driver/sysfs.c:135: warning: ignoring return value of ‘sysfs_create_file’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result
>   /home/pietro/driver/sysfs.c: In function ‘int_exit’:
>   /home/pietro/driver/sysfs.c:155: error: implicit declaration of function ‘schedule_timeout’
>   make[1]: *** [/home/pietro/driver/sysfs.o] Error 1
>   make: *** [_module_/home/pietro/driver] Error 2
>   make: Leaving directory`/usr/src/linux-source-2.6.32'

How can I fix this?

PS: [at this link the whole source file](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3212387/sysfs.c)